# Why function return full html code in console. How return only data(div block)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Why function return full html code in console. How return only data(div block)?

**HTML**
How return data only this block

```
<div class="message_box">
    @foreach(json_decode($message) as $content)
        {{ $content->message }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(function () {
   $.get('chat', function(data){
      console.log(data);
   });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function chat()
{
    $user = User::all();
    $message = MessageModel::orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('chat.chat', ['user' => $user, 'message' => json_encode($message)]);
}
```

Result prtscreen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/80n321q53ambm2f/Untitled-1.png?dl=0)

Comment: Open the network tab and view the response from the server. You're probably getting `404`

Comment: @azium, maybe error only in ajax, laravel code worked.

Comment: `$.get('chat'` ? is chat the valid `route` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, yes, `Route::get('/chat', 'ChatController@chat');`

Comment: Use alias in route file like `Route::get('/chat', array('as'=>'chat','uses'=>'ChatController@chat'));` and in ajax, use it like `{{ URL::route('chat' }}`

Comment: @RayonDabre maybe function return full html code in console, because `return view('chat.chat')`?

Comment: What you want it to be returned ? May be you are looking for something like this: `return Response::json(['user' => $user, 'message' => json_encode($message)]);`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre data `.message_box`. It's chat, real time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99036/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-user3648218).

Answer (score 0):

> **`This problem occurs when you extend layout`**

If you are using **`Laravel 5`** you should check in your view if you have any **`@extend`** directive in blade file or if you are using **`Laravel 4`** you should also check in your controller that if you have any **`$layout`** property

Here you are returning html

```
return view('chat.chat', ['user' => $user, 'message' => json_encode($message)]);
```

Now if you want to return this as **`JSON response`** you have render the HTML & then return the response as an array like this

```
return ['html' => view('chat.chat', ['user' => $user, 'message' => json_encode($message)])->render()];
```

Comment: @user3648218 sorry I don't understand your comment. Can you clear it a bit more?

Comment: your code return json page :) full page it's json :)

Comment: Yes if you want to serve your response you can do it like this way & collect the response from JS as JSON & output it.